# Difference between pip3 and `python3 setup.py install` regarding cmdclass argument

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, setuptools

I tried to configure my package such that a script is executed on the installation process. Therefore, I inherited from setuptools.command install and created my custom class `ActionOnInstall` to do stuff when package is installed. This class is called via setuptools `setup()` argument `cmdclass` as described [here](https://cbuelter.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/extend-the-setuptools-install-command/comment-page-1/).

A minimal example of such a setup.py file looks like

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class ActionOnInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        print("Call install.run(self) works!")
        install.run(self)


setup(name='name',
      cmdclass={
      'install': ActionOnInstall})
```

Building the package by executing

```
pip3 install <path-to-dir-with-setup.py>
```

runs successfully but does not execute commands specified in `ActionOnInstall.run()`. More directly calling this setup.py by

```
python3 setup.py install
```

executes commands specified in `ActionOnInstall.run()`.

Then, I found myself asking: what is the actual difference of these both approaches to install a package. I know, like other posts tell us, pip makes life easier regarding package installation. But how these both approaches treat the `cmdclass` argument of `setup()` differently is not explained. Thus, I would highly appreciate to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pip calls your setup.py but it redirects stdout/stderr. To test setup.py under pip write to a file in a fixed location:

```
class ActionOnInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        print("Call install.run(self) works!", file=open('/tmp/debug.log', 'w'))
        install.run(self)
```

Look into /tmp/debug.log after `pip install .`

Answer (score 4):

pip does run `python setup.py install` when installing your package - it does not change the way your setup.py feel is executed.

The reason you don't see any output is, as @phd mentioned, that pip by default hides all the output from running the `setup.py` file since most of the information printed when running `python setup.py install` is not useful to most users.

You can see this hidden output, along with everything else pip does, by passing the "--verbose" option to `pip install`:

```
$ pip install --verbose ./foo
Processing ./foo
Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-ti0o0gtu-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///Users/pradyunsg/.venvwrap/venvs/t
mp-c0ebb35987c76ad/foo
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Source in /private/var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-ti0o0gtu-build has version 0.0.0, which satisfies requirement foo==0.0.0 from file:///Users/pradyunsg/.ve
nvwrap/venvs/tmp-c0ebb35987c76ad/foo
Could not parse version from link: file:///Users/pradyunsg/.venvwrap/venvs/tmp-c0ebb35987c76ad/foo
Installing collected packages: foo
Running setup.py install for foo ...     Running command /Users/pradyunsg/.venvwrap/venvs/tmp-c0ebb35987c76ad/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/privat
e/var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-ti0o0gtu-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(comp
ile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-cetn8xa9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compi
le --install-headers /Users/pradyunsg/.venvwrap/venvs/tmp-c0ebb35987c76ad/bin/../include/site/python3.6/foo
    running install
    Call install.run(self) works!
    running build
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating foo.egg-info
    writing foo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to foo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to foo.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying foo.egg-info to /Users/pradyunsg/.venvwrap/venvs/tmp-c0ebb35987c76ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-cetn8xa9-record/install-record.txt'
done
Removing source in /private/var/folders/4d/bt0_xfx56bjfmmt2bv3r5_qh0000gn/T/pip-ti0o0gtu-build
Successfully installed foo-0.0.0
Cleaning up...
```