# Hook into setuptools.setup install process

Tags: python, setuptools

I am creating a Python module. I'd like to publish it on PyPI eventually. It has a setup.py, which goes:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mymodule',
    version='1.0',
    author="Seva Alekseyev",
    # ...and more
    )
```

Now, as far as I understand, the invokation for setup.py has an `install` parameter in `argv`, and maybe more. Ergo, not every command line invokation of setup.py is an `install`.

is there a way to perform additional actions on `install` without parsing `argv` myself? In other words, can I somehow feed a piece of "if installing the module, also do this" logic to the `setup()` call?

Targeting Python 3.5+.

Comment: You can [override classes that implements distutils/setuptools' commands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+%22cmdclass%22+install). See [examples for overriding `install`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44123098/7976758).

Comment: Yes. That's why I voted to close as duplicate.